# achieving value of foreign key via python (mariaDB; pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, mariadb, foreign-keys

in my MariaDB table I defined a foreign key such as:

table1:

```
pID - Name    - country
01  - "Steve" - 1
```

where country refers as foreign key to table2 pID (primary key):

table2:

```
pID - Country
01  - "Germany"
```

Now I load the table1 via pandas:

```
dataframe = pd.load_sql("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Name='Steve', engine)
```

and would like to send the results of "Country" into a QComboBox.setcurrentText :

```
QComboBox.setcurrentText(dataframe['country'])
```

Now I am getting a execption as argument 1 has unexpected type 'Series'". The series is shown as

```
(0   1)
```

My question is: how do I get access to the value of the foreign key via python? I would like to add the name of the country.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Regards, Stefan/Steve

I've tried to use the __ syntax in any way, but I didnt find the correct syntax:

```
QComboBox.addItems(dataframe.__country)
```

I've tried to load both tables and reference the index of one to get the value of the other:

```
QComboBox.setCurrentText(df_table2.at[df_table2[df_table2['pID'] == table1.loc[0].at['country']].index.item(), 'Country'])
```

This suprisingly worked - but there must be an easier way?

Comment: If you only run this once, this seems OK. You can simplify `table1.loc[0].at['country']` to `table1.at[0, 'country']`. If you need this in a loop though, there should be a better way, but it depends on what you are doing exactly.